# FBX export is destroying my model

Tags: export, .fbx

Even though everything deforms just fine in Blender, as soon as I go to export it into .fbx and import it anywhere else the model is just obliterated - mesh is all out of wack and the UVs are incorrect.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4YxyDW1.png]

Deleting the armature modifier fixes the geometry (though I need it, obviously). But, the UVs are still wrong and the model seems see-through - and it's *not* a normal issue, all the normals are correct in the 'face orientation' rendering mode.

[image]

I did read a post on here saying that *merging* a rigged mesh could cause issues with the rigging and/or shape keys, but I *joined* all of my separate parts. Not sure if that could cause an issue or not. Plus, the armature and shape keys behave correctly in Blender.

I also tried the Better FBX addon, and that doesn't fix the issue either.

Does anyone have any idea where to even begin debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like Recalculate Outside Normals (`Shift N`) or Recalculate Inside Normals (`Shift Ctrl N`) (or `Edit Mode > Mesh > Normals`). When I tried to use one of my models without doing that previously it just made every sketchy vertex group not load correctly when importing the FBX.

Secondly, check if you have any keyframes. Make sure your Timeline is at `Keyframe 1` and see if the the armature has anything at that point.

Comment: I tried recalculating the normals and that didn't work. The timeline was set at an arbitrary frame but didn't have any keyframes, so I dragged it back to 0 and that didn't work either.